# PMD error in generating report

Tags: pmd

I'm new in using PMD. I've tried to generate an XML report by
 `right-clicking the project > PMD> Generate Reports`

After which this error dialog box appears.

`An internal error occurred during: "RenderReport". java.lang.NullPointerException`

Can someone help me? Why can't I generate report in PMD?